# The console.log I wrote in CytoscapeComponent works as many times as I clicked the buttons on the screen when I clicked on the cy screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cytoscape.js

I want to draw a workflow diagram with the cytoscape library. I want to choose which shape I want to print on the screen with the top buttons. Then every time I press the screen, I expect that shape to appear. But this is not working properly.

There is also a behavior that I do not understand. No matter how many times I pressed the buttons to select the shape, when I clicked on the cy field, I saw that the click event in the CytoscapeComponent worked that many times. and so many nodes are printed on the screen. For example, if I press three buttons and then click on the cy field, three nodes are added to the screen and it is written on the console three times.
Thank you in advance for your help

ReactCytoscapeLibrary.jsx;

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react';
import CytoscapeComponent from 'react-cytoscapejs';

export default function ReactCytoscapeLibrary() {
const [nodeShape, setNodeShape] = useState("");

let myCyRef;

const cyClick = (evt) => {     // runs many times
    myCyRef.add({
        group: 'nodes',
        data: { weight: 75 },
        position: {
            x: evt.position.x,
            y: evt.position.y
        },
        style: { 'shape': nodeShape } 
    });
};

const elements = [
    { data: { id: 'one', label: 'Node 1' }, position: { x: 100, y: 40 } },
    { data: { id: 'two', label: 'Node 2' }, position: { x: 200, y: 80 } },
    { data: { source: 'one', target: 'two', label: 'Edge from Node1 to Node2' } }
];

return (
    <div>
        <div>
            <button id={"ellipse"} style={{ width: "100px", height: "50px", backgroundColor: "red" }} onClick={(evt) => setNodeShape(evt.target.id)}>ellipse</button>
            <button id={"barrel"} style={{ width: "100px", height: "50px", backgroundColor: "red" }} onClick={(evt) => setNodeShape(evt.target.id)}>barrel</button>
            <button id={"vee"} style={{ width: "100px", height: "50px", backgroundColor: "red" }} onClick={(evt) => setNodeShape(evt.target.id)}>vee</button>
        </div>

        <div>
            <CytoscapeComponent
                elements={elements}
                style={{ width: '600px', height: '600px' }}
                cy={cy => {
                    myCyRef = cy;

                    cy.on('click', evt => {
                        cyClick(evt);
                        console.log("Hello");

                    });

                    cy.on("tap", "node", evt => {
                        var node = evt.target;
                        // console.log("EVT", evt);
                        // console.log("TARGET", node.data());
                        // console.log("TARGET TYPE", typeof node[0]);
                        console.log("TARGET ID", node.id());

                    });


                    //REMOVING
                    cy.on('cxttap', 'node', function (evt) {
                        var tgt = evt.target || evt.cyTarget; // 3.x || 2.x

                        tgt.remove();
                    });

                    cy.on('cxttap', 'edge', function (evt) {
                        var tgt = evt.target || evt.cyTarget; // 3.x || 2.x

                        tgt.remove();
                    });
                }}
            />;

        </div>
    </div>
);
}
```

and App.js

```
import './App.css';
import ReactCytoscapeLibrary from './ReactCytoscapeLibrary';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactCytoscapeLibrary />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Ok, I solved this. I needed to use a structure like this; (note: I defined the addNode() function above render())                                                                     <CytoscapeComponent                                                                                                                 ...                                                                                                                                              cy={cy => {
                    myCyRef = cy;
                    cy.unbind("tap");   cy.bind("tap", addNode); ...

Comment: adding code like `cy.on("tap", "node", evt => {` inside HTML is not safe. These event bindings should be made only once. So I suggest to do them on constructor or in a place where things are initialized. Also don't forget to remove the event listeners. This might cause memory leaks.

Comment: @canbax When I try to write my cy.on() or cy.bind() methods on the return method, I get an error. I'll deal with it again when I've done the things I need to add to the program urgently. Thank you for your warning